# When isWritable VS isDefinitelyWritable of ResultSetMetaData can have different values?

Tags: java, sql

Docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html
stays

`isWritable` - "Indicates whether it is possible for a write on the designated column to succeed."

`isDefinitelyWritable` - "Indicates whether a write on the designated column will definitely succeed.
"

Just wonder, under what condition their results can be distinct?